# hybris commerce 6.6 integration with ERP throught datahub using ssl

Tags: tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate, sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

I have installed Hybris Commerce 6.6 and datahub 6.6 and I am trying to establish SSL connection from datahub.

I finished all needed configurations from hybris and data hub side
I created a certificate and added it to java JRE cacerts keystore and I also added it to ERP using STRUST transaction.

When I try to access the data hyb link: https://hybrisc.local:8443/datahub-webapp/v1/version

I get the error:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection hybrisc.local uses an unsupported protocol. ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH Unsupported protocol The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.
```

Comment: Did you try given url as http (without ssl)?

Comment: i found out the problem was that after i created the datahub certificate i moved it to the old datahub keystore and i shouldn't have moved it